# docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error

Tags: docker, runtime, oracle-call-interface

my docker starts giving error after a recent update. Existing containers works but I can not build or run any image.

A simple

> docker run hello-world

gives me an error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/881b53be5cfe91d19577414c2f4a52dd06804624fe1d2189d06c1c3c13f2b4d1/log.json: no such file or directory): runc did not terminate successfully: unknown.

I tried all the tips that are suggested on the internet regarding this issue as restarting, building links, reinstall.....

My current docker version is  18.09.5, Ubuntu 19.04

Does anyone had a similar issue and solved it?

Answer (score 5):

To check the issue by run docker in the debug mode.

1. stop docker with `systemctl stop docker`
2. run docker in debug mode `dockerd --debug`
3. start container with `docker start container_name`

Then check the output in docker debug console in 2.

In my case, it shows

```
ERRO[2020-07-07T23:15:02Z] stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo
ERRO[2020-07-07T23:15:02Z] stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo
```

And solve it by removing the container state folder with `rm -rf /var/run/docker/runtime-runc/moby/docker_id`

Then start your container.

Refer to: [Solving Error response from daemon OCI runtime create failed container with id exists](https://ahmetozer.org/Error-response-from-daemon-OCI-runtime-create-failed-container-with-id-exists.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check the output of `docker version` and see if the client version and daemon version have gone out of sync.

Check the output of following commands `which runc` and `which docker-runc`. If the docker daemon version is 18.09, you should be having runc or else docker-runc.

Comment: Could you explain what > "client version and daemon version have gone out of sync" means ?

Comment: When you run `docker version` command, it will print out two sections. One for "client" and one of "engine". Check the version field in both the sections and make sure they are same or compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I use debian 11 with docker 20.10.5, When I run `docker run hello-world` I got:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: unable
> to retrieve OCI runtime error (open
> /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/2957ad06a6bc7a4f7c7f3fca6b43bde1d6b27600df774f0e8052f4c736300759/log.json:
> no such file or directory): runc did not terminate successfully: exit
> status 139: unknown. ERRO[0010] error waiting for container: context
> canceled

when I run `runc` command , I got "segmentation fault".

I solved it by `apt reinstall runc`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run docker as `docker run ... my_external_script.py`. Because `my_external_script.py` wasn't w/in the docker image I was getting the error. What I did was to set the `scripts` argument w/in my `setup.py` as `scripts=["path/to/my_external_script.py"]` and rebuild docker image. That solved the problem.